# Proving basic fact about ordinals

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

In a set of online lecture notes, I saw the following proposition.

Let $C$ be a set of ordinals. Then $\sup \left\{ \alpha +\beta:\beta\in C \right\} =\alpha +\sup C$.

How can I prove this?

Comment: How was ordinal addition defined?

Comment: @AsafKaragila $\alpha + \beta = \sup\{\alpha+\gamma\mid \gamma<\beta\}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For brevity, we'll write $\beta^+ := \beta+1$ for the successor ordinal of $\beta$.

If $\sup(C) = 0$ then it's trivial.

If $\sup(C) = \beta^+$ a successor ordinal, then $\beta^+ \in C$ so we get that the LHS is $\alpha + \beta^+$ immediately.

If $\sup(C) = \lambda$ a nonzero limit, then if $\lambda \in C$, we're done as above, so suppose it's not in $C$. By definition of ordinal addition, $\alpha + \sup(C) = \alpha + \lambda = \sup \{ \alpha + \gamma : \gamma < \lambda \}$. That sup is the same as $\sup \{ \alpha + \beta : \beta \in C \}$: containment one way is because everything in $C$ is $< \lambda$, while containment the other is because $\lambda$ is the sup of $C$ so for any ordinal less than $\lambda$ we can find a larger ordinal which is also less than $\lambda$.

Comment: Using $\beta^+$ to denote ordinal successors is just terrible.

Comment: @AsafKaragila how would you do it?

Comment: $\beta + 1$?  $\phantom a$

Comment: @PseudoNeo That requires the use of extra brackets to make clear what the point is, surely? $\alpha + (\beta + 1)$? Isn't $\beta^+$ neater?

Comment: No, ordinal addition is associative. And the problem is that $\beta^+$ is the classical notation for the successor cardinal of a given cardinal $\beta$. You could always clarify what you mean (after all, you have the exact same problem for cardinal/ordinal exponentiation), but since the $\cdot + 1$ notation makes everything clearer, it's probably simpler to use it.

Comment: I agree that addition is associative. But the point is that $\beta + 1$ is an element of the set, and I would always prefer to be entirely clear about why each entry of a sum is there. Like $a + \underbrace{b+c}_{\in C} + d$, or $a + (b+c) + d$, rather than just $a + b + c + d$. I just assumed it was clear from context that ordinal succession was meant, since indeed we deal with it with cardinals.

Comment: OK, sorry to have misunderstood you. I agree that it was perfectly clear in the context (I'm not the one who had a cow about it ;-)) but I think I agree with @Asaf that, since an easy disambiguation is available, one might as well use it.